# How to logout with mysql_auth_module?

Tags: php, authentication, authorization

Apache 2.2, php 5.3

I can log on successfully, but how can I logoff?

in apache config:

```
<Directory /www/domain.com/adm>
    AuthName "MySQL group authenticated zone"
    AuthType Basic

    AuthMYSQLEnable on
    AuthMySQLUser user
    AuthMySQLPassword password
    AuthMySQLDB dbname
    AuthMySQLUserTable users
    AuthMySQLNameField email
    AuthMySQLPasswordField pass
    AuthMySQLGroupField group
    AuthMySQLUserCondition " status='on'"
</Directory>
```

After successfull login, apache sets `$_SERVER[PHP_AUTH_USER]` but it's impossible to change/unset this value;

`apache_setenv('PHP_AUTH_USER', '');` and `session_destroy();` don't work too;

`Header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");` doesn't do anything, at least for my FF12;

If I put another authenticate request with 401:

```
Header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"My Realm\"");
Header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
```

it produces login form but I just want to redirect user outside of /adm **without** asking for password again!

I was reading http://www.php.net/features.http-auth for a long time but either I miss something (perhaps very obvious) or it was helpless.

So how can I logoff / logout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as no glue for three weeks - I just discard the nice idea to use mysql_auth_module and fall back to generic auth.

In case you have any ideas - you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You must be try

```
function LogOut() {
    session_destroy();
    session_unset($_SESSION['session_id']);
    header("Location: /auth/", TRUE, 301);   
}
```

Comment: To @Darshan:  Despite I mentioned helplessness session_destroy I have just tried it again. Doesn't work.